# Why can template function parameters of type T& be binded to const lvalues but not rvalues?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider:

```
template <typename T> void f(T&);

const int b = 2;
f(b);      // ok
f(2);      // error, can not bind rvalue to lvalue reference
```

Why is `f(const int)` allowed? the logic seems to indicate that if the programmer did not explicitly define the template parameter as `const T&`, he/she wanted to modify the binded-to variable.

So in this case the question is, why does template instantiation give itself the freedom to instantiate with consts when those were not explicitly required ?

Even if there was a rationale for allowing template instantiation to instantiate with consts, then why, in that case, would be binding to rvalues forbidden? you can bind rvalues to const lvalue references. In that case, the template would be instantiated to `f<const int>`, and `f(2)` would be allowed.

I want to know the reasoning behind these decisions, not references to the standard.

Comment: @NeilButterworth it does because my doubt is in the context of templates since T can either be const int or int. Without templates there would be no doubt.

Comment: Edited to add information. This has nothing to do with the supposed duplicate questions. Neil is wrong in assuming this is not related to templates. read the edit. He is also ignoring the first part of the question. Seems like he only read the code.

Comment: Good question, I've always wondered about this too. It would be great to have an example where the current C++ behavior is expected, not the one you describe. The interesting thing is that `volatile` differs from `const` here. It's logical to `volatile` still be inferred, but not `const`.

Comment: The "Even if there was..." part is kinda solved by the deduction rules for "&&". But the first part is interesting...

Comment: I guess this is to prevent ambiguity. If integer literals were to be either `int` or `const int` then each template that is instantiated with literal could be both. And if there would be `template<class T> f(const T)` and `template <class T> f(T)` both specializations would match the integer literal.

Comment: @nowaqq: `const` isn't part of the signature in your example, so both `f` are the same.

Comment: @geza: You are right, this example was bad. This one should be better: let say we have `template<class T> f(T&)` and `template <class T> f(T)`. In this case if literal could be int or const int (or if it was simply const int) it would match both .

Comment: @nowaqq: yes, its a better example. C++ could have a rule, that in this case, which version is preferred. Or just this would be ambiguous. But, actually, I don't find this interesting too much. The first part of the question, which is more interesting for me, so I let the OP respond to this :)

Comment: It seems the real question is "Why does `T` deduce to `const int` instead of `int` for this call"

Comment: "why does template instantiation give itself the freedom to instantiate with consts when those were not explicitly required ?" is a question from incorrect premise. There is no "freedom". The deduced type matches the argument. Passing a `const int` to `f` deduces `f<const int>`, and passing a `int` to `f` deduces `f<int>`.

Comment: @M.M I'm asking why deducing f as f<const int> is allowed. If the programmer wanted that he would have defined it as f(const T&). It would be analogous to the compiler disallowing things like g(double, int) when g(T, T). It's a matter of compiler implementation.

Comment: @M.M right now, defining f(T&) allows instantiating to both const int and int. And defining f(const T&) only allows instantiating to const int. if you want only non-const instantiations you need special library functions, like those in <type_traits>. Seems cumbersome.

Comment: `f(const T&` deduces `T` to `int` in both cases (not `const int`)

Comment: @M.M yes, that was a mistake. But the issue still stands, f is f(const int&). In the other case f is either f(const int&) or f(int&). Don't see any reason why those two should be allowed at the same time when you can already single out f(const int&)

Answer (score 5):

> Why is f(const int) allowed?

You might subsitute the template `T` by `const int` to transform `T&` into `const int&`

> Even if there was a rationale for allowing template instantiation to instantiate with consts, then why, in that case, would be binding to rvalues forbidden?

There is no `T` (in `T&`) which (exact) matches `int&&` for deduction.

`f<const int>(42)` is allowed, but there is no deduction happening.

> I want to know the reasoning behind these decisions, not references to the standard.

So why allowing cv substitution in template?
I would say it make generic programming easier.
Else you would have to provide overloads for each combination of `const`, `volatile`.

Here, if you want to restrict `T` to non `const`, you may use SFINAE with traits:

```
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const<T>::value> f(T&);
```

Answer (score 4):

> So in this case the question is, why does template instantiation give itself the freedom to instantiate with consts when those were not explicitly required?

Quite simply nothing in the implementation of `f` prevents instantiating the template with `const int`. Try the following instead and you'll observe a problem.

```
template <typename T> void f(T& v) { v = 3; };
const int b = 2;
f(b);      // error: assignment of read-only reference (within the template instance)
int c = 2;
f<const int>(c); // error
```

The fact that b is `const int` means the template is instantiated as `<const int>` and this is not possible because `v` is modified. Explicit instantiation as `<const int>` is similarly disallowed.

> Why is it deduced as `const int`? It should have been deduced as `int`.

When the type to instantiate the template is not explicitly specified, it is deduced based on the type passed into the function which is `const int`. Expecting it deduce a *different* type is impractical (if not outright absurd).

Please also note that if it did deduce the type as `int` then there would be an error passing `const int` into the function. As can be demonstrated by explicitly instantiating the template as `<int>`.

```
template <typename T> void f(T&) {};
const int b = 2;
f<int>(b); //error: no matching function for call to 'f<int>(const int&)
```

> why, in that case, would be binding to rvalues forbidden?

The compiler would need to implicitly assume an appropriate type to use for instantiating the template ***and then*** perform the implicit conversion from rvalue to const lvalue reference. (Seems a a stretch expectation to me.)

Note that if you explicitly instantiate the template as `<const int>` then binding rvalue to const lvalue reference works because the conversion can be done.

```
template <typename T> void f(T&);
f<const int>(2);      // OK
```

Comment: I think that you misinterpreted the first question. In this case, the error would come at `f(b)`, as you would not be able to bind `b` to a non-const reference. Just like in the case if `f` would not be a template. The question is basically: why do cv-qualifiers deduced for `T`?

Comment: @geza Not quite, the error is in the instantiation of the template. The fact that b is `const int` means the template is instantiated as `<const int>` and this is not possible because `v` is modified. Explicit instantiation as `<const int>` is similarly disallowed.

Comment: And that's the OP's question. Why is it deduced as `const int`? It should have been deduced as `int`. OP questions the rationale behind the current behavior. `f`'s logic inherently contains, whether `v` is an input or output parameter. If it's input, it should have marked with `const` in the signature. If it's output, `const` should not deduced for it at all. Or at least that's how I understand it. I don't want to hijack the question.

Comment: @geza Also I don't see how the first question is misinterpreted. **Q:** Why can the the template be instantiated with **const** type? **A:** Because nothing in the code of the template prevents that.

Comment: @geza Ok, I've covered that as well.

Comment: "Expecting it deduce a different type is impractical (if not outright absurd)." It is not different, it just has different qualifiers. To be honest, I think that the current deduction rules can be considered impractical too (at least, before C++11, they were impractical, for sure). "Please also note that if it did deduce the type as int then there would be an error passing const int into the function.": That could be the intent. If `v` is an output parameter, then this should not be allowed. What's the logic behind T being const, then at a `v = ...;` will the instantiation fail?

Comment: @geza  If `v` is an output parameter, then this ***is not*** allowed (as shown in the first part of my answer). In the absence of template code _actually using `v` as an output parameter_, how could the compiler assume that `v` is an output parameter?

Comment: It wouldn't be allowed too, if it worked the way OP described. It would fail at the call site, as T won't be deduced to `const int`, but `int`, so you'll get the same error message what you'd get without templated code (as I've said in my first comment). I don't understand your last question. The question is simple: if `f` is not a template, then you get the error at the call site, if there's a qualifier problem. For templates, needed qualifiers automatically added, which is questionable. Even now, when we have forwarding references. Can you give us an example, where const deduction is useful?

Comment: Before C++11, this behavior was useful, for forwarding parameters (wasn't perfect, but can do the job). But now, with forwarding references, I cannot really think any useful case for this behavior. So, in my opinion, the answer to this question is like "it was useful before, because it allowed forwarding, but now its usefulness is questionable, but because of backward compatibility, it stays".

Comment: I agree with @geza , that's what I was asking, and I don't think the current answers are answering that. I guess this answer does resolve the second part of the question, although explaining the reasoning behind keeping template parameter conversions so simple would improve it.